# Connect telnet with WebLogic

Tags: java, telnet, aix

I’m dealing with a huge issue on a java 1.5 based application that was developed a few years ago.

Application is accessed from nearly 600 handheld devices (pretty old ones by the way) that connect to a .jar located in my AIX server. Connections are made via telnet. The problem is that every single connection from a handheld creates a new operative system session, which hits server performance and ends up taking it down.

I’d like to know if there’s a way to create those telnet connections without having to create those sessions in the OS.

Comment: Si señor me interesa que la migremos al sitio en ingles... Muchas gracias por la recomendación.

Comment: Si quiere la puedo traducir al español

Comment: What's an operative system session?

Comment: It is when a terminal is connected to the SO with telnet